# Scrape a script tag containing specific text

Tags: python, selenium, web-scraping, beautifulsoup

I am currently trying to scrape the "imageToken" value from a script tag from the below page source, the python code below will get the token about 75% of the time, but the other times the number of the script tag must be changing and it is selecting the wrong tag.

Is there any way to search through all the scrip tags for specifically the tag that contains the "imageToken"?

here is the code that is working 75% of the time.

```
    html_source = driver.page_source
    soup = BeautifulSoup(html_source, 'html.parser')
                
    scripts = soup.find_all('script')[20]
    findtoken = scripts.string.split(',')[58]
    token = findtoken.split(':')[2].strip('"')
    print(token)
```

I have also tried this but nothing is returned:

```
    html_source = driver.page_source
    soup = BeautifulSoup(html_source, 'html.parser')
                
    scripts = soup.find_all('script')
    for script in scripts:
        if 'imageToken' in script:
            print(script)
```

here is the source of the `script` tag, there are a lot of other scripts on the page also but this is the only one with the "imageToken".

```
<script>

                ((data) => {
                    /* TASK: Fix this. Move away from F3.page */
                    window.F3 = window.F3 || {};
                    window.F3.page = window.F3.page || {};
                    Object.assign(window.F3.page, data);
                })({"user":{"email":"email@address.com","useFacebookPhoto":false,"joinDate":"2021-02-05T10:11:11-07:00","hasIcon":false,"confirmed":true,"disabled":false,"hasPassword":true,"ancestrySubscriber":false,"admin":false,"accountStatus":"monthly-subscriber","subscriptionStatus":"subscriber","FreeAccess":true,"accountState":{"signedOut":false,"registered":true,"subscriber":true,"expiring":false,"freeTrialSubscriber":false,"payingSubscriber":true,"bundleSubscriber":false,"newspaperSubscriber":false,"acomSubscriber":false,"formerSubscriber":false,"formerPayingSubscriber":false,"formerBundle":false,"currentSubscriptionType":"monthly","currentAccountStatus":"monthly-subscriber","oldSubscriptionStatus":"subscriber"},"passwordSerial":1,"userId":6812311,"username":"myusername"},"totalImages":585709948,"config":{"api":{"host":"http://svc.fold3.com:50000","f3Api":"http://api.fold3.com/fold31-api","path":"/fold31/api"},"app":{"canonical":"https://www.fold3.com","cookieDomain":".fold3.com","env":"live","goStack":"https://go.fold3.com","hostname":"www.fold3.com","trustedHostname":"fold3.com"},"ancestry":{"domain":"https://www.ancestry.com","internalDomain":"ancestry.int","redirectHost":"https://www.fold3.com","clientId":"60e8bf12987c2a38a1f48b3c8e41f4400d3b7eb2","redirectPath":"/auth/openid","ssoPath":"/sso/oidc/authorize"},"fold3":{"contactNumber":"1-800-613-0181"},"image":{"host":"https://img.fold3.com","hostRotating":"https://img#.fold3.com","path":"/img/"},"oldStack":{"host":"http://php.fold3.com:9090"},"regiment":{"host":"http://regiment.fold3.com","path":"/fold31-regiment/api"},"search":{"host":"http://search-es.fold3.com","path":"/fold31-search/api"}},"isMobile":false,"image":{"imageToken":"4IIROAS9p-z9rCHcF2toENYedok9hGmwdOsdlKGAfCzNNch2fNPT9HcElRYXBOL66kcnDgT7C9-aivjlk5o4Kwlgc7HB6U_MeIjtQuF2mMrfZq6dsivylzR2d30JiKv46hcMyMMwmBuRSI9_TlCelg==","imageId":692219369,"publication":{"dbid":61641,"mediaProvider":"EMS","allowDownloadDoc":true,"allowAnnotations":true,"hasOcr":false,"recordCountMode":"images","rollupImage":"NONE","lastModification":"2020-10-14T11:06:06-06:00","lastSorted":"2020-10-15T09:16:04-06:00","configuredAccessLevel":"REGISTERED","maximumAccessLevel":"REGISTERED","minimumAccessLevel":"REGISTERED","featured":false,"hashPath":"hiOcMlUzt","publicationId":1104,"contentType":"IMAGE"</script>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To search a tag containing specific text, you can use the `:contains(<my text>)` Selector.

In your example to see if the `script` contains the text `imageToken` use:

```
print(soup.select_one("script:contains('imageToken')"))
```

---

Note: To use a Selector use the [`select()`](https://www.crummy.com/software/BeautifulSoup/bs4/doc/#css-selectors) method instead of `find_all()`, Or `select_one()` instead of `find()`.

Comment: excellent thanks this has worked. i thought there might have been an option with beautiful soup to search for a specific phrase, like with selenium.

Answer (score 0):

your second method is right but it missing `.string`

```
for script in scripts:
    if 'imageToken' in script.string: # <== add .string
        print(script.string)
```

Comment: thanks for your help, when trying this i get an error "TypeError: argument of type 'NoneType' is not iterable"

Comment: did your code has `scripts = soup.find_all('script')` ?

Comment: then it must be your `html_source` is empty or does not contain `<script>`

Comment: ok ill look into it, the other solution has worked, using soup.select_one("script:contains('imageToken')") thanks for your help.

Comment: check out this demo https://onlinegdb.com/S1hTTebMO

Comment: ok i see, there are other script tags in the html source, if that has anything to do with it.